# How to build array from json input file in python 3?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

I am trying to build an array from the information comming from a local json file.

The desired output array format is:

```
output = [
        'elementa-element2-element3',
        'elementa-element2-element3',
]
```

The input from json is:

```
import json
with open('/Users/user/test.json', 'r') as f:
    array = json.load(f)
print (array)

{'responseHeader': {'zkConnected': True, 'status': 0, 'QTime': 2, 'params': {'q': 'facet_gender:man', 'start': '0', 'fq': 'lang:de', 'rows': '10000', 'wt': 'json', 'facet': 'true'}}, 'response': {'numFound': 1005, 'start': 0, 'docs': [
{'rmc': 'm228238-0042', 'title': 'Day-Date 40', 'family': 'Day-Date', 'familyCode': 'day-date', 'facet_case_title': ['Oyster, 40 mm, Gelbgold']}, 
{'rmc': 'm326935-0007', 'title': 'Sky-Dweller', 'family': 'Sky-Dweller', 'familyCode': 'sky-dweller', 'facet_case_title': ['Oyster, 42 mm, Everose-Gold']}, ...
```

How can I acess the rows and build my array from all rows?

```
 output = array
 while i < len(array)
    output[i] = array['response']['docs'][i]['familyCode']+'/'+array['response']['docs'][i]['rmc']
```

Comment: `array['response']['docs'][0]`

Comment: ahh... great! Forgot the 'repsonse'

Comment: You need to provide more information in your question and make it more clear and understandable. What exactly is the issue here?

Comment: still need to figure out how to cycle through that and bild my array as I am new to python. Somehting I might find out, your info helped me.

Comment: You need to define an order for the contents of each `docs`, and build the array based on the order.

Comment: @iBug I edited the question an added the while loop. As I am new to python I am struggling with the syntax. Getting "NameError: name 'i' is not defined"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The json.load() will return a [dictionary](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_dictionaries.asp). This dictionary can be nested, if the json file contains nested elements. This is the case in your example, too.
If you format your json a little bit, it will be more clear:

```
{
  'responseHeader': {
    'zkConnected': True,
    'status': 0,
    'QTime': 2,
    'params': {
      'q': 'facet_gender:man',
      'start': '0',
      'fq': 'lang:de',
      'rows': '10000',
      'wt': 'json',
      'facet':
      'true'
    }
  },
  'response': {
    'numFound': 1005,
    'start': 0,
    'docs': [
      {'rmc': 'm228238-0042', 'title': 'Day-Date 40', 'family': 'Day-Date', 'familyCode': 'day-date', 'facet_case_title': ['Oyster, 40 mm, Gelbgold']},
      {'rmc': 'm326935-0007', 'title': 'Sky-Dweller', 'family': 'Sky-Dweller', 'familyCode': 'sky-dweller', 'facet_case_title': ['Oyster, 42 mm, Everose-Gold']},
      ...
    ]
  }
}
```

**If you want to retrieve the "docs", you actually need this:**

```
array["response"]["docs"]
```

In your example, it is a [list](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists.asp), and it can be used as you would normally do.

*Example 1: get the first element of the list*

```
documents = array["response"]["docs"]  # Create new variable "documents".
print(documents[0])  # Print out first element of "docs" variable.
```

*Example 2: Iterate over every element:*

```
documents = array["response"]["docs"]
for document in documents:
    print(document)
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked! Do you also know the answer to my related question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54081264/string-indices-must-be-integers-error-while-trying-to-build-a-list-from-json-i