# "string indices must be integers" error while trying to build a list from json input

Tags: python

I am trying to create a list from a dictiory made from a json file in Python 3.7.

The json file has the following structure:

```
watches 
   collection
    model   
        0   {…}
        1   
           rmc  
              0 "value_I_need"
              1 "value_I_need"
```

json extract:

```
{"watches":{"collection":{"event_banner":{"type":"banner","margin":false,"mobile_layer":true,"class":"tdr-banners-events","media":{"type":"image","src":"/public/banners/events/baselworld_2017_navigation.jpg","height":"150px"},"text":{"align":"left","animate":true,"positioning":"left","suptitle":"BANNER_EVENT_A_TITLE","title":"BANNER_EVENT_A_SUPTITLE","title_type":"h2","style":"light","link_text":"BANNER_EVENT_A_LINK_TEXT","link_href":"/magazine/article/baselworld-2017"}},"collection-navigation":{"type":"view","template":"nav.tdr-collection-navigation.tdr-flex.tdr-flex--align-items-center > ul.tdr-collection-navigation__list.tdr-flex.tdr-flex--align-items-flex-start@list","children":[{"type":"view","template":"li.tdr-collection-navigation__item","insert":{"where":"list"},"children":[{"type":"button-gamma","text":"FIND_YOUR_TUDOR_COLLECTION","href":"/search","cssClass":"tdr-button--gamma-collection-navigation","children":[{"type":"new-icon","cssClass":"circleicon dark-reverse-red","insert":{"where":"icon"},"icon":"search","width":"16","height":"16","colorClass":"tdr-icon-dark"}]}]},{"type":"view","template":"li.tdr-collection-navigation__item","insert":{"where":"list"},"children":[{"type":"collection-navigation-item","index":"0","text":"GRID_VIEW_COLLECTION","children":[{"type":"new-icon","cssClass":"red","insert":{"where":"icon"},"icon":"icon-grid","width":"36","height":"36","colorClass":"tdr-icon-dark"}]}]},{"type":"view","template":"li.tdr-collection-navigation__item","insert":{"where":"list"},"children":[{"type":"collection-navigation-item","index":"1","text":"LIST_VIEW_COLLECTION","children":[{"type":"new-icon","cssClass":"red","insert":{"where":"icon"},"icon":"icon-list-3","width":"36","height":"36","colorClass":"tdr-icon-dark"}]}]},{"type":"view","template":"li.tdr-collection-navigation__item.collection-navigation__item--new-collection","insert":{"where":"list"},"children":[{"type":"collection-navigation-item-new-collection","index":"2","text":"FEATURED_SELECTION","children":[{"type":"new-icon","cssClass":"red","insert":{"where":"icon"},"icon":"switch","width":"63","height":"63","colorClass":"tdr-icon-dark"}]}]}]},"collection_filter":{"0":{"route":"all","name":"all_collection","model_page":["black-bay","new-black-bay-fifty-eight","black-bay-32-36-41","new-black-bay-gmt","black-bay-chrono","black-bay-steel","black-bay-s-g","black-bay-dark","black-bay-bronze","north-flag","pelagos","new-1926","style","glamour-double-date","glamour-date-day","glamour-date","heritage-advisor","heritage-chrono","heritage-ranger","fastrider-black-shield","clair-de-rose","classic"]},"1":{"route":"featured-selection","name":"featured_selection","model_page":["glamour-double-date","new-black-bay-32","new-1926","black-bay-chrono"]},"length":2,"all":0,"featured-selection":1},"model":{"0":{"route":"black-bay-32-36-41","watch_model":"black_bay_32_36_41","model_group":"tudor","fam_intro_title":"bb32_36_41_intro_title","fam_intro_text":"bb32_36_41_intro_text","flagship_rmc":"m79580-0003","page_link":"/watches/black-bay-32-36-41/","tags":[],"optional_calibre":false,"no_wrap":true,"family_filter":true,"aggregated":true,"rmc":["m79540-0007","m79540-0009"]},

print(documents)
{'0': {'route': 'black-bay-32-36-41', 'watch_model': 'black_bay_32_36_41', 'model_group': 'tudor', 'fam_intro_title': 'bb32_36_41_intro_title', 'fam_intro_text': 'bb32_36_41_intro_text', 'flagship_rmc': 'm79580-0003', 'page_link': '/watches/black-bay-32-36-41/', 'tags': [], 'optional_calibre': False, 'no_wrap': True, 'family_filter': True, 'aggregated': True, 'rmc': ['m79580-0003', 'm79580-0004',
```

My code to build the list:

```
with open('test.json', 'r') as f:
    dictionary = json.load(f)
documents = dictionary["watches"]["collection"]["model"]
for document in documents:
    models = document["rmc"]
    try:
        for model in models:
            start_urls.append('https://www.example.com/'+document['page_link']+'/'+model+'.html')
    except Exception: 
        pass
```

The traceback error:

```
models = document["rmc"]
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

The rmc values are another list within the model listing. So each model might have another list of rmc values.

My goal is to create a list of all models including their variantes (rmc).

Why is pyhton telling me it is a string, while I believe rmc rows are listed in integers?

Comment: What is the type of `document`, try `type(document)`?

Comment: it returns: <class 'str'>

Comment: document might be of string type here and not dict

Comment: Instead of giving incorrect syntax, please post the minimal repeating unit of the JSON file.

Comment: Well that is the problem `document` is a string not a dictionary.

Comment: I must access the fields wrong. Please have a look at the updated question with parts of json file.

Comment: @merlin could you check that json string again? Currenty, it's invalid.

Comment: @DanielScott I tried to only post part of it. Now updated and included the entire header.

Comment: @merlin In "rmc" there are extraneous quotes.

Comment: Try validating json here https://jsonlint.com/

Comment: Are you sure `"model":` is followed by `{`? The error you're getting would happen if it's followed by a double quote.

Comment: Please fix the formatting of the JSON, it impossible to understand as it is now. Also the error message tells, that the type of the `document` is a string. Doesn't it  string in you model?

Comment: I corrected the error and added also the printout of "documents"

Answer (score 1):

You seem to think your `model` value is a list. The JSON says otherwise:

```
"model":{"0":{"route":"black-bay-32-36-41",
```

It's a dict whose keys are strings. You iterate over that dict:

```
for document in documents:
```

When you iterate over a dict that way, you iterate over the *keys* of that dict, so `document` holds the string `"0"`. The string cannot be indexed by another string as `document['rmc']`, so Python rightly complains.

You can fix it in a couple of ways. First, you can change the way you read the model:

```
for document in documents:
    models = documents[document]['rmc']
    ...
```

Or you can change the way you iterate over the dict:

```
for idx, document in documents.items():
    models = document['rmc']
```

Pretty-printing the JSON instead of leaving it as one inscrutable line would probably have alerted you to this issue much faster.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I am getting an error: "Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable" with both variants.

Comment: The full traceback should indicate the line of code where you have an int that's being subscripted. Evidently, there's a variable on that line that doesn't hold the value you think it does. Use a debugger or print some values to check your assumptions. Consider using `repr` so that ints are displayed differently from strings that happen to contain only numeric characters.

Answer (score 0):

## Fix JSON Identifiers

The true,false statements were also causing an error (not valid identifiers). I was able to fix it with the following lines:

```
with open('test.json', 'r') as f:
    dictionary = json.loads(f.read().replace("true","1").replace("false","0"))

for document in dictionary:
    for i in range(len(dictionary['watches']['collection']['model'])):
        models = dictionary['watches']['collection']['model'][str(i)]

        try:
            for i in range(0,len(models)):
                _string = ('https://www.example.com'+models['page_link']+models['rmc'][i]+'.html')
                print(_string) # This will show each generated string before processing
                start_urls.append(_string)
        except Exception as e: 
            pass
```

## Access as a List

The contents of `models` is a list. Accessing a "list inside of a dict" is a bit different than accessing a dict. We needed to find the length of the list and iterate through it, because the elements aren't associated with string names.

Comment: how do I clean this up?

Comment: This must be a copying error, or he would be getting an error from `json.load()`.

Comment: @Barmar Great point! Merlin, could you double check this please?

Comment: That is indeed a copy error that occured while I was trying to minimize the example.

Comment: @merlin Could you update the question with the corrected JSON please?

Comment: @DanielScott I update it, and added the printout for "document". Most likely I am just using a wronng syntax as I am new to python.

Comment: @merlin I've updated the answer. Check if it works for you.

Comment: Thank you @DanielScott, I am still getting an error. This time: "Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module> TypeError: string indices must be integers"

Comment: @merlin Okay, is your line 2 `dictionary = json.load(f)` ?

Comment: @merlin It is working for me now. Just had to reformat some of the json identifiers. I've pasted the modified JSON string I used for validation.

Comment: Thank you @DanielScott. I tried your code but the json.load gives me the following err: AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'replace'. If I load it simply with json.load(f), it will load the json.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186327/discussion-between-daniel-scott-and-merlin).

Comment: nice! That fixed the error and retrieved the first record, thank you. What is missing now is the iterating for every record. models = dictionary['watches']['collection']['model']['0'], gets all variants of the first model. But how do I get the entire json into that list of URLs? models = dictionary['watches']['collection']['model']['1'], models = dictionary['watches']['collection']['model']['2'], etc.

Comment: @merlin There you go, try that.

Comment: Hi Scott, this returns 24 results and then a key error "25" as there are 24 rows, but followed by a string and not a dataset. There are actually about 400 elements (urls) in this json if each rmc is unique to one model. Your code outputs 24 models but the underlying variants (rmc) are not in the output. I tried it as well, and am close to give up on this. Seemed to be an easy task at first, but my python skills are limited :-)

Answer (score -1):

Change this line:

```
documents = dictionary['watches']['collection']['model']
```

To this:

```
documents = dict(dictionary['watches']['collection']['model'])
```

And documents will become a dictionary

Comment: What do you think it is currently?

Comment: The current value of `documents` is a string. You can't use the `dict()` function to turn a string into a dictionary.

Comment: You can. I do it all the time.